# Why is my git head detached in PhpStorm and how is it caused by my git sub directory?

Tags: git, phpstorm

I am working in PhpStorm and I noticed that my automatic deployment doesn't work. I noticed a git warning on my PhpStorm which probably caused this behavior:

[image]

Apparently my git head is detached on my master branch. To be more precise, a git sub folder (`./core`) has caused the problem since it has new commits. I pulled the latest version in the the git sub folder `./core` and now it is up to date.

But the PhpStorm warning doesn't disappear and my git root folder still tells me that the sub module has problems. When I look into Source Tree, the problem seems to be the commit hash:

[image]

[image]

I have no idea how to fix this. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: That's a *submodule* and it is therefore *supposed to be in detached HEAD state*. The superproject (the parent directory and its corresponding Git repository) is a separate Git repository. The superproject has, in each commit, the raw hash ID that the submodule should use. Extract a superproject commit (in the usual way) and run `git submodule update` and the superproject Git runs the equivalent of `(cd core; git checkout <hash>)` to detach its HEAD to the desired commit.

Comment: If that's not the commit *you* desire, your goal is to check out a commit in the superproject, then do your own `(cd core; git checkout ...)` operation to get a *different* commit out in the submodule, then back in the superproject, run `git add core` and `git commit`. You've now made a *new* superproject commit that says "get me back the hash ID I got manually earlier", so the *next* time you check out this (new, superproject) commit and use `git submodule update`, that's the (submodule) commit you'll get.

Comment: How phpstorm interacts with all of this, I don't know—that's up to phpstorm.